# Kotlin: Omitting enum name when its unambiguous

Tags: kotlin, enums, kotlin-when

With [Swift enums](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Enumerations.html) you can omit the name of the `enum` in cases where only a value of that type can be used.

So when given the enum (Swift/Kotlin)

```
enum (class) CompassPoint {
  case north
  case south
  case east
  case west
}
```

Swift only needs the enums name when creating a new variable:

```
// type unclear, enum name needed
var directionToHead = CompassPoint.west

// type clear, enum name can be dropped
directionToHead = .east

// type clear, enum name can be dropped
switch directionToHead {
case .north:
  print("Lots of planets have a north")
case .south:
  print("Watch out for penguins")
case .east:
  print("Where the sun rises")
case .west:
  print("Where the skies are blue")
}
```

While in Kotlin, for the same situation you'd have to write

```
// type unclear, enum name needed
var directionToHead = CompassPoint.west

// type clear, enum name still needed
directionToHead = CompassPoint.east

// each case needs the enum name
when(directionToHead) {
  CompassPoint.north -> println("Lots of planets have a north")
  CompassPoint.south -> println("Watch out for penguins")
  CompassPoint.east -> println("Where the sun rises")
  CompassPoint.west -> println("Where the skies are blue")
}
```

Is there a reason for this, and/or are there situations in Kotlin where just `.north` or `north` can be used?

> Edit: It seems importing the enum 'fixes' this and is necessary even when the enum is defined in the same file as it is used.

While this helped practically, I still don't understand why the import is needed.

Comment: If you add a static import of the enum, the enum class name can be omitted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Edit: It seems importing the enum 'fixes' this and is necessary even when the enum is defined in the same file as it is used.
>
> While this helped practically, I still don't understand why the import is needed.

Simply because it isn't treated specially. `import CompassPoint.*` lets you write just `<name>` for anything you'd write as `CompassPoint.<name>` without it (if the name doesn't conflict with anything). If you happen to be in the file where `CompassName` is defined, it works exactly the same.

You can refer to the values as `north` etc. without imports *inside the enum definition*, exactly like you can refer to an `object`'s members inside this object:

```
object Obj {
    val v = 0
    val v1 = v
}

val v2 = Obj.v
```

or

```
import Obj.* // or import Obj.v
val v2 = v
```

Answer (score 6):

Just use import, so you can use enum values without enum name

```
  import CompassPoint.*
```

Comment: CompassPoint is defined in the same file as the `when`. edit: oh.. but it still fixed it. Thats super weird.. but thanks!

Comment: Even if it is in the same file or same class, you need the import

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, the Kotlin team is considering implementing unqualified enum constants when the enum type is unambiguous.

They're currently doing a feature survey to gather feedback, and [unqualified enum constants](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2021/06/kotlin-features-survey-edition-2/#unqualified-enum) are on there too.